# Use of pos­ses­sive apos­tro­phe with the sec­ond word of a com­pound proper noun like “Aus­tralian States”

Tags: grammatical-number, punctuation, apostrophe, proper-nouns, compounds

I have a rel­a­tively sim­ple ques­tion, but I am just a lit­tle con­fused
and po­ten­tially mis­in­formed. My un­der­stand­ing is that when
plu­ral­is­ing a pos­ses­sive noun, you add an apos­tro­phe af­ter the *‑s*.
So for ex­am­ple, *the par­ent**s’** car* or *the boy**s’** Play­Sta­tion* – I am
fairly sure that is cor­rect gram­mar.

How­ever, I do not know what the rule is when pre­sented with a com­pound
noun such as *Aus­tralian States*.  I will put down three pos­si­bil­i­ties:

1. Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian **States’** up­per house of par­lia­ment.
2. Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian **State’s** up­per house of par­lia­ment.
3. Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian **States** up­per house of par­lia­ment.

Which one is it? I would ap­pre­ci­ate jus­ti­fied an­swers be­cause this
is re­ally bug­ging me!

Comment: _Australian States_ doesn't seem to be an official name, but _United States Senate_ is written without an apostrophe. However, I think this is a compound noun in itself rather than a possessive. With compound common nouns, the noun part is normally treated like any other noun - _the bower birds' nests_.

Comment: ... I'd go further and query the claim that _Australian S/states_ is a compound noun. _British counties_ isn't ... perhaps a strong collocation. // With the _United States Senate_, I'd class _United States_ as a compound attributive (though the 3-orthographic-word string could easily be seen as a compound noun). In either case, there is no apostrophe.

Comment: I'm not convinced "States" should be capitalised here, which may be causing some confusion. The Australian government website doesn't routinely capitalise state or territory, [example](https://www.australia.gov.au/states). "Australian states" isn't like "United States" (a short form of the country name). So "state" is just a regular common noun and can be treated like any other.

Comment: Each Australian state has a bicameral parliament, which means the phrase, regardless of what comes before or after) should read, "Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian states up­per houses of par­lia­ment." This leaves me uncertain that "states" doesn't need an apostrophe after the s.

Comment: Australian states' upper houses of parliament.  = the upper houses of parliament of the Australian states. BUT: one set of parents: the parent's car. The boys' Playstation.

Comment: @Lambie I agree up until BUT. Isn't "the parent" singular? "Mrs. Crumcake, the parent, argued with the school teacher. The parent's argument was ridiculous." Mr. and Mrs. Crumcake, the parents, argued with the school teacher. The parents' argument was ridiculous." Are you contending that's wrong? BTW, I would like someone to tell me why my comment above yours isn't helpful. Who is the arbiter of helpfulness?

Comment: @Lambie - One set of parents is still two people, so _the parents' car_ surely?

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, I have to disagree with this one. By your same logic, 'boys' could consist of a single set of sons. In fact, you can consider any plural noun as a single group of the singular noun. But that is why we have specific conventions. It is _parents'_

Comment: @KateBunting in regard to your first commend, I agree that you are correct in saying that 'states' shouldn't be capitalised. However, _"the bower birds' nests"_ - is the same structure. To compare the two, _"Australian"_ is _"bower"_, _"states"_ is "birds'" and _"upper houses"_ is _"nests'"_ So, surely by equivalence the apostrophe would go to 'states'? Because the "states" belong to Australia and the "states" are possessive to the "upper houses".

Comment: @DatBoi - I'm not familiar with Australian political terminology, but I couldn't find any reference online to _Australian States_. It was someone else who said it shouldn't be capitalised. But _United States Senate_ is a compound name, not something 'belonging to' the USA.

Comment: @KateBunting _United States Senate_ is different because it denotes **one** senate of the compound noun _"United States"_. _"Australian states"_ is grouping all the states in Australia, it is not synonymous with _"Australia"_. And since I am making _"states"_ possessive to "_upper houses_", surely, _states_ requires an apostrophe after the 's'?

Comment: @DatBoi - As I said, I'm not familiar with the Australian political system, but if _each_ state has a parliament, I agree it should be _states' upper houses_. (The OP wrote _house_ in the singular.)

Answer (score 1):

They are called *State upper houses* (in Australia). The compound noun is *State upper house[s]*, not *Australian State[s]*. So,

> Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian State up­per house**s** of par­lia­ment

(not one of your options) would seem correct. If you want to avoid confusion, you might write:

> Be­long­ing to Aus­tralia's State up­per house**s** of par­lia­ment

or

> Be­long­ing to the State up­per house**s** of par­lia­ment in Australia

https://www.parliament.nsw.gov.au/researchpapers/Pages/state-upper-houses-in-australia.aspx

However,

> Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian state**s'** up­per house**s** of par­lia­ment

should also be fine. Note that in this case we wouldn't capitalise *state[s]*. But the plural *houses* stays.

Comment: Your answer is on the right track, but I'm still not sure it's correct (see my comment above). Some questions demand more consideration than they get from the showrunners.

Comment: @Zan700 I've edited to incorporate another solution.

Comment: Australian states' upper houses of parliament = the upper houses of parliament of the Australian states. No doubt about it.

Comment: @Lambie I tend to agree (as in my answer, at the bottom), but in this case, I wanted to have an answer that at least acknowledges the capitalisation of _State[s]_ (as this seems to be a premise of the question).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that capitalization. That doesn't change it, though, does it?

Comment: @Lambie I feel it does, a bit. You wouldn't write "There are 50 *S*tates in the United States." So, in my mind, capitalisation suggests that _State upper house[s]_ should be/is considered a compound noun. If not, then _states' upper houses_ is probably better.

Comment: Australian States' upper houses of parliament//I was looking more at those.

Comment: @Ridici I believe what you added was "Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian states' up­per houses of par­lia­ment." This seems logical to me. However, I read the linked paper and it does include ". . . functions of State upper houses in Australia . . ."along with "Upper Houses."  Aside from the OP's examples or the linked article, have you seen state/states capitalized?

Comment: _"Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian State up­per houses of par­lia­ment"_, this sentence doesn't apply in the context. It holds ambiguity as to each state having multiple upper houses, or whether the group of states has multiple upper houses. It doesn't provide context because _"Australian State"_ is singular.

Comment: _"Be­long­ing to Aus­tralia's State up­per houses of par­lia­ment"_, this one definitely hits the mark better, but it is a bad flowing sentence. In speech, there is an invisible comma after _"State"_, so you probably have to hyphenate "state-upper-houses" - I'm not sure. It makes it a lot more clear when the "State" is pluralised.

Comment: _"Be­long­ing to the Aus­tralian states' up­per houses of par­lia­ment"_, back to the one that I am not sure about. By pluralising _"houses"_, you again leave some ambiguity as to whether there is one, or more than one upper house in each state.